# Flink JDBC Sink and connection pool

Tags: jdbc, apache-flink, connection-pooling

I cannot find any info in docs about connection reusing in `JDBCAppendTableSink` in Flink. Should I use my own connection pool or Flink reuses connection for me?
Is this really a gap in the documentation or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Each instance of the sink creates a connection when the sink is created, and that connection (and a prepared statement) are then automatically reused for you.